# What exactly does it mean to say that a conference is "peer reviewed"?

Tags: publications, conference, peer-review

I think as a PhD student, you should publish only in high IF journals rather than conferences. But if it is conference, then it should be at least "peer reviewed" one!

Some conferences first ask for an abstract. After the selection based on only abstracts they ask for a limited page number paper (like 3-4 pages). After all, you receive no any comments from any Reviewers. At best case, some few typographical comments from the editor.

Is this called peer reviewed?

Comment: Check this: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38086/why-are-conference-papers-so-important-in-cs

Answer (score 7):

Things vary a bit, depending on the field you are in.
Some fields only review and publish abstracts (e.g., medicine), in some fields conferences are more important than journal publications (e.g., computer science).

But as a rule of thumb: a conference is only considered to be peer-reviewed when the full paper is reviewed, and not an (extended) abstract.

Personally, I think that there are great conferences out there, where only an extended abstract is reviewed (e.g., SPIE), but many working in academia do not consider them to be peer-reviewed.

Be aware! There are also scam (or near-scam) conferences that pretend to have a peer-review process, but actually hardly perform any review at all (and have accepted computer generated nonsense papers in the past). Try to avoid these! They only cost (a lot of) money, and will actually degrade your CV.

Comment: I don't at all agree with your second paragraph. At least in what I do, you have conferences with extended abstracts (12 pages) that _are_ considered peer-reviewed.

Comment: @yo', 12 pages is much more than an extended abstract!

Comment: @BillBarth Then it's a matter of terminology I think :)

Comment: In my field, 12 pages is above the maximum length of full papers for most conferences.

Comment: Some conferences in computer science confusingly call "extended abstract" the papers that are submitted and reviewed there (usually around 12 pages). I guess this is because they are supposed to be a shorter version of an upcoming journal paper. In my experience, if these are peer-reviewed, then this is a peer-reviewed conference presentation, the term "abstract" isn't important.

Comment: as @BillBarth said, I have submitted an "extended abstract" to ION GNSS+ consisting of 12 pages. However, not all accepted extended abstracts undergo a peer-review